Will the starting temperature of a substance affect the calculations of enthalpy of neutralisation?
In an experiment where you are attempting to calculate the enthalpy of an acid-base reaction for different acids (but the same base), what effects will having a higher or lower temperature for the base solution have on the calculations?
(Temperature change is noted down periodically throughout the neutralisation reaction)

Each mixing event will result in a change in the recorded temperature superimposed on the effect of the enthalpy released during the neutralization. Assume the acid and base solutions are at initial temperatures (before mixing) $T_1$ and $T_2$, and assume the original and the mixed solutions have the same specific heat capacity. The final T of the mixture is then given by
$$q_1=-q_2 \\ \implies C_1\Delta T_1 = -C_2\Delta T_2 \\ \implies m_1 C_s (T_\textrm{f}-T_1) = -m_2 C_s (T_\textrm{f}-T_2)\\ \implies  T_\textrm{f} = \frac{m_1T_1 + m_2T_2}{m_1+m_2}\\ \implies  T_\textrm{f} = \chi_{\textrm{w}1}(T_1 -T_2) + T_2$$
Here $\chi_{\textrm{w}1}=m_1/m$, $C$ is the total heat capacity, and $C_s$ the specific heat capacity. Therefore if the temperatures and amounts of the solutions mixed were noted then a correction should be possible.
The case I have described is simply mixing of two solutions at a different temperature. There is no discussion of heat produced during the titration due to the chemical reaction. That can be treated separately once the final temperature has been corrected for the difference in temperature of the solutions.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
